# Socket.io and Nodejs: Sending response to multiple clients and change not being saved(?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, server, client-server

**EDIT: My first problem has been solved (rather simple). The second question is still valid, and for this one, I have no clue how to fix the problem.**

I'm making a multiplayer Sudoku game. I am new to Nodejs and socket, so please correct me if my thinking is wrong along the line.

It's a work in progress and here's what I am trying to do at the moment: When the user inputs a value into one of the cells, it emits a request(?) using the index of that cell to the server. The server then finds the correct answer from the answer sheet it has and sends the result back to the client. Then the javascript code follows through and if the correct input was placed, it will put that answer in for all users (**note: I am assuming the user is inputting the correct answer FOR NOW; I will work on the wrong answer part afterwards**).

**The Problems:**

1) Right now, the correct answer will lock in for the person who submitted the right answer in the cell, but it will not show for all clients.

2) If I submit an answer to another cell (whether correct or not), it will delete the past change - that is, the cell that the user inputted previously and became "locked in"

Here is my javascript code:

```
function closeCellInput($cell) {
    var index     = $boardCells.index($cell);
    // var target    = findTarget(index); //SHOULD BE SERVER
    socket.emit('target', index);
    socket.on('targetResult', function(data){
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        var target = data;
        var number    = $cell.find('input').val();
        var complete  = false;

        $cell.empty().removeClass('empty').removeClass('solved').attr('style', null);
        socket.emit('index', index);

        if (number == target) {
            $cell.text(number).addClass('solved');
            complete = true;
            socket.emit('solved', number);

            //complete = checkComplete();
        }
        else if (number != '') {
            var cell      = $cell[0];
            var animator  = new Animator({duration:750});
            var animation = new ColorStyleSubject(cell, "background-color", "#FF8888", "#FFFFFF");

            $cell.text('').addClass('empty');
            animator.addSubject(animation).play();
            //$cell.html('<input type="text"/>').find('input').focus();
            //adding above line does not make the red light blinkerino
        }
        else {
            $cell.text('').addClass('empty');
        }

        $selected = $([]);
    });




}
```

Here is my relevant server code (if needed):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('solved', function(val){
        console.log('number value: ' + val)
    });

    socket.on('target', function(index){
        //Hard coded answers for now, but will be changed later
        var solution = "435269781682571493197834562826195347374682915951743628519326874248957136763418259";

        console.log('index: ' + solution[index]);
        socket.emit('targetResult', solution[index]);

    });
```

});

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It does not appear that you are broadcasting any events to all clients in your server code. Did you omit that section? Might explain #1

Edit: To clarify, it appears that your "response" events from the server are only being emitted to the client that initiated them.

Comment: I thought this was the case. How might I go about broadcasting events to all clients? I am new to Node and Socket, so I am not too sure how to do this.

EDIT: I fixed the broadcasting problem (rather simply actually haha).

Comment: To *all* clients, or just ones in a specific *room*? Here's the relevant section of the documentation for that. http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Or, most briefly, `io.sockets.emit()`

Comment: Since the server code in the OP question gave a scenario without rooms, I posted an answer specifically for that. But Sean Ryan is more than right that if you want multiple games at the same time, you might want to investigate more about creating different rooms :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code server:

```
socket.on('target', function(index){
    //Hard coded answers for now, but will be changed later
    var solution = "435269781682571493197834562826195347374682915951743628519326874248957136763418259";

    console.log('index: ' + solution[index]);
    socket.emit('targetResult', solution[index]);

});
```

you emit only to the **socket that the sender is connected to**. In order to emit to everyone, use the following syntax:

```
socket.on('target', function(index){
    //Hard coded answers for now, but will be changed later
    var solution = "435269781682571493197834562826195347374682915951743628519326874248957136763418259";

    console.log('index: ' + solution[index]);
    io.sockets.emit('targetResult', solution[index]);

});
```

Notice that I changed `socket.emit` to `io.sockets.emit`. This makes `socket.io` broadcast to all connected sockets.

As mentioned by Sean Ryan, the socket.io docs have a section about different rooms if you want to broadcast only to players that are connected to the same game: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Thanks! I'll continue working on it and see if I can get it to work the way I want it to. And yep, I do plan on having multiple rooms (though that was more like "after I can get this to work first" thing). 

I'm still trying to figure out the javascript problem haha. I think I have ideas though. Hopefully they're good ones!

Comment: So did it work right with `io.sockets.emit`?
Send a link to your game once it's ready. Might be fun! :-)